# How can I deploy a Flask app using Tesseract 5.3.1 in Azure? What will be the Dockerfile?

Tags: python, deployment, dockerfile, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am building a Flask app for which I am using Tesseract version 5.3.1 in Windows. [Tesseract 5.3.1](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki).

My Dockerfile looks like this:

`RUN apt-get install -y tesseract-ocr`

**The issue is it is installing Tesseract 4.1.1 (Linux Distribution)** which is significantly slower than 5.3.1. How can I use the Tesseract 5.3.1 while deploying the app? Please suggest what would be the Dockerfile in order to perform this?

I tried various approaches [from this link](https://techviewleo.com/how-to-install-tesseract-ocr-on-ubuntu/), but didn't find a working solution or any sample Dockerfile for this.

Comment: What about using a Tesseract based image to build off of? When you say you tried the linked approach, what did not work about it? It looks to have a Dockerfile you can use and several strategies you could potentially use if you did not like that dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

These steps helped me to install Tesseract 5.3.1 in my docker image (base is mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.9)([reference](https://github.com/Franky1/Tesseract-OCR-5-Docker))

1. Download the zip file of code from
   https://github.com/Franky1/Tesseract-OCR-5-Docker and extract to the folder where your DockerFile is.
2. Add the following lines to your DockerFile

   ```
   COPY Tesseract-OCR-5-Docker-main /    
   ARG TESSERACT_VERSION="5.3.1"    
   ARG TESSERACT_URL="https://api.github.com/repos/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/tarball/$TESSERACT_VERSION"     
   RUN apt-get install --no-install-recommends --yes \
   apt-transport-https \
   asciidoc \
   automake \
   bash \
   ca-certificates \
   curl \
   docbook-xsl \
   g++ \
   git \
   libleptonica-dev \
   libtool \
   libicu-dev \
   libpango1.0-dev \
   libcairo2-dev \
   make \
   pkg-config \
   wget \
   xsltproc \
   && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*    
   WORKDIR /src    
   RUN wget -qO tesseract.tar.gz $TESSERACT_URL && \
   tar -xzf tesseract.tar.gz && \
   rm tesseract.tar.gz && \
   mv tesseract-* tesseract    
   WORKDIR /src/tesseract    
   RUN ./autogen.sh && \
   ./configure && \
   make && \
   make install && \
   ldconfig    
   #go to default traineddata directory
   WORKDIR /usr/local/share/tessdata/    
   #copy language script and list to image
   COPY Tesseract-OCR-5-Docker-main/get-languages.sh .
   COPY Tesseract-OCR-5-Docker-main/languages.txt .    
   #make script executable
   RUN chmod +x ./get-languages.sh
   #download traineddata languages
   RUN ./get-languages.sh
   WORKDIR /home
   ```
3. You can add to install your requirements and other required steps after this in the DockerFile.

   ```
   COPY requirements.txt /home/site/wwwroot/    
   RUN  pip install -r /home/site/wwwroot/requirements.txt
   ```